# Pandas - add a column with value computed based on another column value in current and previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the dataframe below,

```
colNames = ["Time","Col2","Col3","Col4","Col5","Col6","Col7","Col8","Col9","Col10","Col11","Col12","Col13"]
colVals = [['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '89', '891', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '891', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '891', '13', ''], ['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '891', '15', ''], ['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '891', '16', ''], ['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '891', '17', ''], ['05:17:55.703', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '891', '18', ''], ['05:17:55.707', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '185', '892', '0', ''], ['05:17:55.707', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '185', '892', '1', ''], ['05:17:55.707', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '73', '892', '5', ''], ['05:17:55.707', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '185', '892', '6', ''], ['05:17:55.707', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '73', '892', '7', ''], ['05:17:55.708', '268', '4', '28', '-67.60', '13', '', '2', '', '', '', '', '2'], ['05:17:55.711', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '57', '892', '10', ''], ['05:17:55.711', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '201', '892', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.711', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '25', '892', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.723', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '893', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.723', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '893', '15', ''], ['05:17:55.723', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '893', '16', ''], ['05:17:55.726', '268', '4', '', '-67.80', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.728', '', '', '28', '', '12', '31', '2', '3', '185', '894', '0', '1'], ['05:17:55.728', '', '', '', '', '', '31', '', '3', '185', '894', '1', ''], ['05:17:55.731', '', '', '', '', '', '31', '', '3', '217', '894', '10', ''], ['05:17:55.731', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '894', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.731', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '894', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.731', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '894', '13', ''], ['05:17:55.743', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '895', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.743', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '895', '15', ''], ['05:17:55.743', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '895', '16', ''], ['05:17:55.746', '268', '4', '', '-67.82', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.747', '', '', '28', '', '13', '20', '2', '3', '185', '896', '1', '2'], ['05:17:55.747', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '185', '896', '2', ''], ['05:17:55.747', '', '', '', '', '', '30', '', '3', '217', '896', '5', ''], ['05:17:55.751', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '217', '896', '10', ''], ['05:17:55.751', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '896', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.751', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '896', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.751', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '896', '13', ''], ['05:17:55.763', '', '', '', '', '', '31', '', '3', '217', '897', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.763', '', '', '', '', '', '30', '', '3', '217', '897', '15', ''], ['05:17:55.763', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '897', '16', ''], ['05:17:55.763', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '897', '17', ''], ['05:17:55.766', '268', '4', '', '-67.13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.768', '', '', '28', '', '12', '20', '2', '3', '185', '898', '3', '2'], ['05:17:55.768', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '217', '898', '6', ''], ['05:17:55.771', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '217', '898', '10', ''], ['05:17:55.771', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '898', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.771', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '898', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '899', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '41', '899', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '25', '899', '13', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '899', '15', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '899', '16', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '899', '17', ''], ['05:17:55.784', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '899', '18', ''], ['05:17:55.786', '268', '4', '', '-67.66', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.788', '', '', '28', '', '13', '18', '2', '3', '185', '900', '0', '2'], ['05:17:55.788', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '185', '900', '1', ''], ['05:17:55.788', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '185', '900', '2', ''], ['05:17:55.788', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '41', '900', '5', ''], ['05:17:55.788', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '185', '900', '6', ''], ['05:17:55.791', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '105', '900', '7', ''], ['05:17:55.791', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '89', '900', '8', ''], ['05:17:55.791', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '217', '900', '10', ''], ['05:17:55.791', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '900', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.791', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '25', '900', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.806', '268', '4', '', '-67.50', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.808', '', '', '28', '', '12', '31', '2', '3', '185', '902', '0', '1'], ['05:17:55.808', '', '', '', '', '', '31', '', '3', '185', '902', '1', ''], ['05:17:55.808', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '25', '902', '2', ''], ['05:17:55.808', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '25', '902', '3', ''], ['05:17:55.808', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '217', '902', '5', ''], ['05:17:55.808', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '217', '902', '6', ''], ['05:17:55.811', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '89', '902', '7', ''], ['05:17:55.811', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '121', '902', '8', ''], ['05:17:55.811', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '217', '902', '10', ''], ['05:17:55.811', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '902', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.811', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '73', '902', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.811', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '9', '902', '15', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '902', '16', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '25', '902', '17', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '902', '18', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '217', '903', '0', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '903', '1', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '19', '', '3', '105', '903', '2', ''], ['05:17:55.815', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '41', '903', '3', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '903', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '9', '903', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '105', '903', '13', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '903', '15', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '903', '16', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '121', '903', '17', ''], ['05:17:55.823', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '89', '903', '18', ''], ['05:17:55.826', '268', '4', '', '-67.51', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.828', '', '', '28', '', '12', '18', '2', '3', '185', '904', '0', '1'], ['05:17:55.828', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '185', '904', '1', ''], ['05:17:55.828', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '185', '904', '2', ''], ['05:17:55.828', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '185', '904', '3', ''], ['05:17:55.828', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '217', '904', '5', ''], ['05:17:55.828', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '217', '904', '6', ''], ['05:17:55.831', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '904', '7', ''], ['05:17:55.831', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '169', '904', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.831', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '904', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.831', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '904', '13', ''], ['05:17:55.846', '268', '4', '', '-67.01', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.848', '', '', '28', '', '13', '19', '2', '3', '57', '906', '1', '2'], ['05:17:55.848', '', '', '', '', '', '19', '', '3', '41', '906', '2', ''], ['05:17:55.848', '', '', '', '', '', '19', '', '3', '73', '906', '3', ''], ['05:17:55.848', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '217', '906', '5', ''], ['05:17:55.848', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '217', '906', '6', ''], ['05:17:55.848', '', '', '', '', '', '19', '', '3', '9', '906', '7', ''], ['05:17:55.851', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '121', '906', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.851', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '57', '906', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.851', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '105', '906', '13', ''], ['05:17:55.855', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '906', '15', ''], ['05:17:55.855', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '906', '16', ''], ['05:17:55.855', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '105', '906', '17', ''], ['05:17:55.855', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '185', '907', '0', ''], ['05:17:55.855', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '907', '1', ''], ['05:17:55.855', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '9', '907', '2', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '907', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '57', '907', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '153', '907', '13', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '907', '15', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '217', '907', '16', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '57', '907', '17', ''], ['05:17:55.864', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '105', '907', '18', ''], ['05:17:55.867', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '185', '908', '0', ''], ['05:17:55.867', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '185', '908', '1', ''], ['05:17:55.867', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '9', '908', '2', ''], ['05:17:55.867', '', '', '', '', '', '16', '', '3', '73', '908', '6', ''], ['05:17:55.868', '268', '4', '28', '-66.79', '13', '', '2', '', '', '', '', '2'], ['05:17:55.871', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '105', '908', '7', ''], ['05:17:55.871', '', '', '', '', '', '20', '', '3', '25', '908', '8', ''], ['05:17:55.871', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '217', '908', '10', ''], ['05:17:55.871', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '908', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.871', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '9', '908', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.871', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '121', '908', '13', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '908', '15', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '908', '16', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '57', '908', '17', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '73', '909', '0', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '909', '1', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '89', '909', '2', ''], ['05:17:55.875', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '89', '909', '3', ''], ['05:17:55.886', '268', '4', '', '-67.48', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.888', '', '', '28', '', '12', '31', '2', '3', '185', '910', '0', '1'], ['05:17:55.888', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '89', '910', '1', ''], ['05:17:55.888', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '9', '910', '2', ''], ['05:17:55.888', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '185', '910', '3', ''], ['05:17:55.888', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '217', '910', '5', ''], ['05:17:55.888', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '217', '910', '6', ''], ['05:17:55.891', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '89', '910', '7', ''], ['05:17:55.891', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '73', '910', '8', ''], ['05:17:55.891', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '217', '910', '10', ''], ['05:17:55.891', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '910', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.891', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '57', '910', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.900', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '911', '3', ''], ['05:17:55.900', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '217', '911', '5', ''], ['05:17:55.900', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '217', '911', '6', ''], ['05:17:55.900', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '105', '911', '7', ''], ['05:17:55.900', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '25', '911', '8', ''], ['05:17:55.900', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '217', '911', '10', ''], ['05:17:55.903', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '911', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.903', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '57', '911', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.903', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '153', '911', '13', ''], ['05:17:55.903', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '911', '15', ''], ['05:17:55.903', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '911', '16', ''], ['05:17:55.903', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '137', '911', '17', ''], ['05:17:55.906', '268', '4', '', '-67.79', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.908', '', '', '28', '', '13', '18', '2', '3', '57', '912', '0', '2'], ['05:17:55.908', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '185', '912', '1', ''], ['05:17:55.908', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '57', '912', '2', ''], ['05:17:55.908', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '137', '912', '5', ''], ['05:17:55.908', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '169', '912', '6', ''], ['05:17:55.923', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '913', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.923', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '89', '913', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.926', '268', '4', '', '-68.13', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.928', '', '', '28', '', '13', '31', '2', '3', '185', '914', '0', '2'], ['05:17:55.928', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '105', '914', '2', ''], ['05:17:55.928', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '25', '914', '5', ''], ['05:17:55.928', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '121', '914', '6', ''], ['05:17:55.928', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '25', '914', '7', ''], ['05:17:55.931', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '89', '914', '10', ''], ['05:17:55.931', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '914', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.931', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '73', '914', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.939', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '137', '915', '5', ''], ['05:17:55.939', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '153', '915', '6', ''], ['05:17:55.939', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '73', '915', '7', ''], ['05:17:55.939', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '153', '915', '10', ''], ['05:17:55.943', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '915', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.943', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '137', '915', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.943', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '137', '915', '15', ''], ['05:17:55.943', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '217', '915', '16', ''], ['05:17:55.943', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '105', '915', '17', ''], ['05:17:55.946', '268', '4', '', '-67.45', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.948', '', '', '28', '', '9', '30', '3', '3', '160', '916', '0', '3'], ['05:17:55.948', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '121', '916', '1', ''], ['05:17:55.948', '', '', '', '', '', '21', '', '3', '105', '916', '2', ''], ['05:17:55.948', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '73', '916', '5', ''], ['05:17:55.948', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '137', '916', '6', ''], ['05:17:55.959', '', '', '', '', '', '13', '', '4', '217', '917', '3', ''], ['05:17:55.959', '', '', '', '', '', '11', '', '4', '217', '917', '5', ''], ['05:17:55.959', '', '', '', '', '', '11', '', '4', '217', '917', '6', ''], ['05:17:55.959', '', '', '', '', '', '13', '', '4', '217', '917', '7', ''], ['05:17:55.959', '', '', '', '', '', '13', '', '4', '217', '917', '8', ''], ['05:17:55.959', '', '', '', '', '', '11', '', '4', '153', '917', '10', ''], ['05:17:55.963', '', '', '', '', '', '13', '', '4', '217', '917', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.963', '', '', '', '', '', '13', '', '4', '121', '917', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.966', '268', '4', '', '-67.22', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.968', '', '', '28', '', '12', '14', '2', '4', '57', '918', '1', '2'], ['05:17:55.968', '', '', '', '', '', '14', '', '4', '185', '918', '2', ''], ['05:17:55.968', '', '', '', '', '', '12', '', '4', '169', '918', '5', ''], ['05:17:55.983', '', '', '', '', '', '14', '', '4', '57', '919', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.983', '', '', '', '', '', '14', '', '4', '217', '919', '12', ''], ['05:17:55.983', '', '', '', '', '', '14', '', '4', '9', '919', '15', ''], ['05:17:55.983', '', '', '', '', '', '14', '', '4', '217', '919', '16', ''], ['05:17:55.983', '', '', '', '', '', '14', '', '4', '217', '919', '17', ''], ['05:17:55.986', '268', '4', '', '-67.80', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:55.988', '', '', '28', '', '13', '14', '2', '4', '9', '920', '1', '1'], ['05:17:55.988', '', '', '', '', '', '14', '', '4', '41', '920', '2', ''], ['05:17:55.988', '', '', '', '', '', '14', '', '4', '57', '920', '3', ''], ['05:17:55.988', '', '', '', '', '', '12', '', '4', '217', '920', '5', ''], ['05:17:55.988', '', '', '', '', '', '12', '', '4', '217', '920', '6', ''], ['05:17:55.988', '', '', '', '', '', '14', '', '4', '41', '920', '7', ''], ['05:17:55.991', '', '', '', '', '', '14', '', '4', '89', '920', '8', ''], ['05:17:55.991', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '217', '920', '11', ''], ['05:17:55.991', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '89', '920', '12', ''], ['05:17:56.003', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '25', '921', '11', ''], ['05:17:56.003', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '121', '921', '12', ''], ['05:17:56.003', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '25', '921', '13', ''], ['05:17:56.003', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '217', '921', '15', ''], ['05:17:56.003', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '217', '921', '16', ''], ['05:17:56.003', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '217', '921', '17', ''], ['05:17:56.006', '268', '4', '', '-67.31', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['05:17:56.008', '', '', '28', '', '10', '22', '3', '3', '9', '922', '1', '3'], ['05:17:56.008', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '73', '922', '2', ''], ['05:17:56.008', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '121', '922', '5', ''], ['05:17:56.008', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '185', '922', '6', ''], ['05:17:56.011', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '217', '922', '7', ''], ['05:17:56.011', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '121', '922', '11', ''], ['05:17:56.011', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '89', '922', '12', ''], ['05:17:56.020', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '105', '923', '5', ''], ['05:17:56.020', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '185', '923', '6', ''], ['05:17:56.020', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '25', '923', '7', ''], ['05:17:56.020', '', '', '', '', '', '31', '', '3', '112', '923', '10', ''], ['05:17:56.023', '', '', '', '', '', '31', '', '3', '112', '923', '11', ''], ['05:17:56.023', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '217', '923', '12', ''], ['05:17:56.023', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '217', '923', '13', ''], ['05:17:56.023', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '217', '923', '15', ''], ['05:17:56.023', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '217', '923', '16', ''], ['05:17:56.023', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '217', '923', '17', ''], ['05:17:56.023', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '217', '923', '18', ''], ['05:17:56.027', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '57', '924', '0', ''], ['05:17:56.027', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '41', '924', '1', ''], ['05:17:56.027', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '185', '924', '2', ''], ['05:17:56.027', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '185', '924', '3', ''], ['05:17:56.027', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '73', '924', '5', ''], ['05:17:56.027', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '217', '924', '6', ''], ['05:17:56.028', '268', '4', '28', '-67.68', '13', '', '2', '', '', '', '', '2'], ['05:17:56.039', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '217', '925', '3', ''], ['05:17:56.039', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '217', '925', '5', ''], ['05:17:56.039', '', '', '', '', '', '17', '', '3', '217', '925', '6', ''], ['05:17:56.039', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '217', '925', '7', ''], ['05:17:56.039', '', '', '', '', '', '18', '', '3', '57', '925', '10', ''], ['05:17:56.043', '', '', '', '', '', '22', '', '3', '73', '925', '16', '']]

df = pd.DataFrame(colVals, columns=colNames)
df = df.set_index('Time')
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Need to add new `Col14`, such that it starts from 0 and increment by one whenever value in `Col11` of current row is less than the value in `Col11` of previous row - if the previous row's `Col11` value is `NaN`, it shouldn't increment `Col14`.

For example

```
+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Col11 | Col14 |                                                                                                 |
+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 900   |     0 | start with 0                                                                                    |
| NaN   |     0 |                                                                                                 |
| 900   |     0 |                                                                                                 |
| 903   |     0 |                                                                                                 |
| 904   |     0 |                                                                                                 |
| 904   |     0 |                                                                                                 |
| 8     |     1 | increment Col14 by 1 when current row's Col11 value is less than the previous row's Col11 value |
| 8     |     1 |                                                                                                 |
| 200   |     1 |                                                                                                 |
| 201   |     1 |                                                                                                 |
| NaN   |     1 | if Col11 is NaN, Col12 takes same value as prev row                                                                               |
| 0     |     2 | increment Col14 by 1 when current row's Col11 value is less than the previous row's Col11 value |
| 1     |     2 |                                                                                                 |
| NaN   |     2 |                                                                                                 |
| NaN   |     2 |                                                                                                 |
| 0     |     3 | increment Col14 by 1 when current row's Col11 value is less than the previous row's Col11 value |
+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is there a way to get reference to the previous row ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
df['col14']=df.Col11.gt(df.Col11.shift(-1)).cumsum()
```

or

```
df['col14a']=df.Col11.gt(df.Col11.shift(-1)).shift().fillna(0).cumsum().astype(int)
```

The difference between the two is that the count switches at the end of lower value (in the first one) and it switches at the start of new value (2nd one)

If you want to consider NaN same as the previous non-Nan value, you the code below.

```
df['col14b']=df.Col11.fillna(method='ffill').gt(df.Col11.fillna(method='ffill').shift(-1)).shift().fillna(0).cumsum().astype(int)
```

With the smaller dummy dataset you provided, output is below

```
Col11   col14   col14a  col14b
0   900.0   0   0   0
1   NaN     0   0   0
2   900.0   0   0   0
3   900.0   0   0   0
4   903.0   0   0   0
5   904.0   0   0   0
6   904.0   1   0   0
7   8.0     1   1   1
8   8.0     1   1   1
9   200.0   1   1   1
10  201.0   1   1   1
11  NaN     1   1   1
12  0.0     1   1   2
13  1.0     1   1   2
14  NaN     1   1   2
15  NaN     1   1   2
16  0.0     1   1   3
```

**Details**
I am explaining the last one here, the other two are similar to this.

With `df.Col11.fillna(method='ffill')` we are filling the NaN with the previous valid values, so tha out put is as below (we are not changing Coll11, we are just using this while creating the new column)

```
0     900.0
1     900.0
2     900.0
3     900.0
4     903.0
5     904.0
6     904.0
7       8.0
8       8.0
9     200.0
10    201.0
11    201.0
12      0.0
13      1.0
14      1.0
15      1.0
16      0.0
```

With `df.Col11.fillna(method='ffill').shift(-1)` we are just shifting 1 row up so that we can do the comparison between the row & it's previous row.

```
0     900.0
1     900.0
2     900.0
3     903.0
4     904.0
5     904.0
6       8.0
7       8.0
8     200.0
9     201.0
10    201.0
11      0.0
12      1.0
13      1.0
14      1.0
15      0.0
16      NaN
```

With `df.Col11.fillna(method='ffill').gt(df.Col11.fillna(method='ffill').shift(-1))`, we do the comparison & the result is true of false, as below.

```
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6      True
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11     True
12    False
13    False
14    False
15     True
16    False
```

We use `shift` to shift the value one row down since you want the number to switch when the smaller number is present. When we shift rows down, the very first row becomes `NaN`, we are replacing that with 0 (since we have to start with zero) using `.fillna(0)`. Then we use `.cumsum()`. `.cumsum()` adds only `True` values so, we get the values we need. Finally, we assign this column as integer with `.astype(int)` to make all the values as integers.

Comment: this doesn't give the desired results. `Col14` should increment when the value of `Col11` is lower than the one in the previous row.

Comment: Just change `lt` (less than) to `gt` (greater than). Code updated. However, it seems that none of the rows are less than the one in the previous row in your dataset.

Comment: would it handle NaN as in the updated smaller dummy dataset

Comment: this works !!. care to explain the different operations which are done ?

Comment: Details added. Check it out.